# How to validate a textbox that it must contain the values starting from fixed combination of words?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate a textbox that it must contain the values starting from fixed word "temp", User must enter temp before entering any other thing in the textbox.
Please help.

Regards.

Comment: What have you got so far? What kind of validation? (I.e server side or client side?)

Comment: `textbox.value.indexOf('temp') === 0` ?

Comment: It is a client side validation, I want to force user to write temp before anything in the text box.

Comment: what if the user pastes stuff from the clipboard?

Comment: Is it possible for you to append "temp" to start with and then use the keypress event to check for backspaces while keeping tracking of the number of new chars typed? For example append "temp", count = 0, if they try to backspace have the keypress event ignore for count = 0. Once they type more characters increment and decrement count, but dont allow backspace? I'm sure there is a much better way to do this with more validation but it's just a thought, where's my coffee?!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried regular expressions?  Regular expressions are a way to see if a string contains a specified sequence of characters, and is much more robust than a simple 'search'!  They're a powerful tool and I would suggest google for a tutorial.

I noticed you said this is client side, so [here's a page describing regexp in javascript.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)  I haven't used regular expressions in javascript, but they can be very useful.  Of course, regular expressions are also available in C#.

Basically you'll want to use "^temp" as your pattern.  The '^' will make sure that the matching starts at the beginning of the string you're testing, and check to see if 'temp' is there.  If the pattern doesn't match, the string doesn't have 'temp' at the start of it.

```
var stringToTest = "TemP this should match"
var pattern = /^temp/i
var result = pattern.test(stringToTest)
```

Above is a simple example [that I pulled from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp).  As you see, the pattern uses '^temp' as its pattern, and it uses the modifier 'i' to make the check case-insensitive, so that it doesn't matter how the user types in 'temp'(Could be Temp, temP, teMp, teMP, tEmp, etc).